# How to create a Singleton timer with a coroutine for a Kotlin Android app with various fragments?

Tags: android, kotlin, timer, singleton, runnable

In my android app, which I made in Kotlin, I used a Timer and a Runnable to repeat a certain set of tasks. 
However, I quickly ran into issues, as my app had a bottom navigation and therefore, everytime I clicked on a different navigation item like (home, profile, settings, etc) and returned back to the fragment with the Runnable, the timer was behaved erratically. It seemed to me that multiple timers were being created and somehow, were not being destroyed.

A quick solution was to use a Singleton so initialize one instance with a timer and synchronize it with whatever function I want it to repeat.

However, coming from Java I had no knowledge of using a Singleton in Kotlin. I did some research and found out that to make a singleton, you declare it as `object SingletonName` and you just use it. It's that simple (as mentioned by various dev blogs)

So, I basically want a timer to be in a singleton and then repeat a certain amount of tasks in a fragment with a runnable, without ever having to maintain another timer.
How do I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Creating a Singleton was easy. As easy as writing

```
object SyncTimer {

    //TODO:Your code here

}
```

Since, I was doing UI operations, I wanted to use a Co-routine, which will be maintained in the Singleton itself.

So I added the dependency in my `build.gradle` (app level)

```
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.2"
```

Next up, we create the co-routine with the runnable. For my usage, I'll initialize the runnable in my `Dashboard.kt` file. The Dashboard activity contains all my other fragments in the bottom navigation (home, profile, settings, etc.)

```
object SyncTimer{
    //You can supply your own runnable from Fragments
    private lateinit var userRunnable: Runnable


    fun init (){
        val handler = Handler()

        GlobalScope.launch {

            if(userRunnable == null){
                userRunnable = Runnable {
                    Log.d("SyncTimer", "Working without any inputs")
                }
            }

            val swipeTimer = Timer()
            swipeTimer.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
                override fun run() {
                    handler.post(updateUi())
                }
            }, 1000, 2000)
        }
    }


    fun set(runnable : Runnable) {
        Log.d("SyncTimer", "A runner was provided")
        userRunnable = runnable
    }

    private fun updateUi(): Runnable{
        return userRunnable
    }

}
```

Then in my Dashboard activity, I initialize the Runnable like in the `onCreate()`

```
        SyncTimer.init()
```

With this, the timer and runnable have initialized. My dashboard quickly defaults to the `HomeFragment`, where in the `onCreateView()` I pass a runnable of my own to the `set()`:

```
val updateUi = Runnable {
                //Your code here
        }

        SyncTimer.set(updateUi) // <- Pass your runnable here
```

If you have noticed, I've used an `if statement` in the singleton, where if `userRunnable == null` then pass a default runnalbe, that prints into the logs, "Working without any inputs"
However, when my app starts, I always get "A runner was provided" in the logCat. This means that the Runnable worked right from the first instance, with the runnable I passed on to it with the `SyncTimer.set()`

Now, even if I change to different fragments, the timer is maintained. and Only when I return to the `HomeFragment` the code to update ui is called again.

Therefore the cleanest version of the code is:

```
object SyncTimer{
    private lateinit var userRunnable: Runnable

    fun init (){
        val handler = Handler()

        GlobalScope.launch {
            val swipeTimer = Timer()
            swipeTimer.schedule(object : TimerTask() {
                override fun run() {
                    handler.post(updateUi())
                }
            }, 1000, 2000)
        }
    }

    fun set(runnable : Runnable) {
        Log.d("SyncTimer", "A runner was provided")
        userRunnable = runnable
    }

    private fun updateUi(): Runnable{
        return userRunnable
    }

}
```

Initialize with

```
SyncTimer.init()
```

Pass a runnable

```
val runnable = Runnable {
    //TODO: Do something
}
```

The beauty of this code is that you can pass different runnables in different fragments and they'll all work without any new timers being created.

Improve upon this code:

- How do you create different `timers` with different `delays` and `periods`?